# Sort a key with optional object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following data as Input and I am trying to get the desired output as a result of sorting the data:

**Input**

```
[
    {
        "info": { "name": "abc" }
    },
    {
        "info": { "name": "def" }
    },
    {
        "info": {},
        "stats": { "packages": 10, "score": 10 }
    },
    {
        "info": {},
        "stats": { "packages": 5, "score": 8 }
    },
    {
        "info": {},
        "stats": { "packages": 7, "score": 6 }
    }
]
```

**Desired Output - Sort by packages descending, if present**

```
[
    {
        "info": {},
        "stats": { "packages": 10, "score": 10 }
    },
    {
        "info": {},
        "stats": { "packages": 7, "score": 6 }
    },
    {
        "info": {},
        "stats": { "packages": 5, "score": 8 }
    },
    {
        "info": { "name": "abc" }
    },
    {
        "info": { "name": "def" }
    }
]
```

So far I have this code to filter data that has stats object, apply sort on it and then combine it with data that does not stats object. I am wondering if there's an efficient way to do this.

```
filterData = [];
sortedData = [];
filterData = [...filterData, ...data.filter(x => x.stats)];
filterData.sort((a, b) => b.stats.packages.localeCompare(a.stats.packages));
sortedData = [...filterData, ...data.filter(x => !x.stats)];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define a custom sort function. A sort function takes in two arguments (elements from the array) and returns either a positive, negative, or zero value, depending on which element is considered bigger. Read about it more here: [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Next up, to see if the `package` variable exists you can use [Optional_chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "info": { "name": "abc" }
    },
    {
        "info": { "name": "def" }
    },
    {
        "info": {},
        "stats": { "packages": 10, "score": 10 }
    },
    {
        "info": {},
        "stats": { "packages": 5, "score": 8 }
    },
    {
        "info": {},
        "stats": { "packages": 7, "score": 6 }
    }
]

const sorted = arr.sort((item1, item2) => 
    (item2?.stats?.packages || 0) - (item1?.stats?.packages || 0)
)
console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: It is in this answer too

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have hundreds of data it should be efficient enough.
Alternatively, you can use or write sort function like that:

```
data.sort((a, b) => (b.stats?.packages ?? 0) - (a.stats?.packages ?? 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [optinal-chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), and [nullish-operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```js
const data = [
  { "info": { "name": "abc" } },
  { "info": { "name": "def" } },
  { "info": {}, "stats": { "packages": 10, "score": 10 } },
  { "info": {}, "stats": { "packages": 5, "score": 8 } },
  { "info": {}, "stats": { "packages": 7, "score": 6 } }
];

const sorted = data.sort((a, b) =>
  (b?.stats?.packages ?? 0) - (a?.stats?.packages ?? 0)
);

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved with [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#param%C3%A8tres) , and a custom sort function using a [ternary condition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator);
the sort function must return either a positive value, a negative value, or zero. depending on the weight of the 2 values to be processed

custom function details:
1 we test if the stats object is present if yes we assign the value of stats.packages otherwise we assign 0 (for the first as well as the second object)
2 then we compare the two results
we will therefore have a sort on the stats, while the position of the values without stats will remain unchanged

```js
data = [
    {
        "info": { "name": "abc" }
    },
    {
        "info": { "name": "def" }
    },
    {
        "info": {},
        "stats": { "packages": 10, "score": 10 }
    },
    {
        "info": {},
        "stats": { "packages": 5, "score": 8 }
    },
    {
        "info": {},
        "stats": { "packages": 7, "score": 6 }
    }
]
const sorter = (a,b)=>{
  let aa = a.stats?a.stats.packages:1;
  let bb = b.stats?b.stats.packages:1;
  return bb - aa;
}
data.sort(sorter);
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: done! ...  i will be more specific next time